# 'str_iterator' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm messing about with [pyxshell](http://nojhan.github.io/pyxshell/), which is a library that basically provides some syntactical sugar for itertools.

The core class is PipeLine, which is passed an iterator in its constructor, and which calls the passed iterator when its iterator is called:

```
class PipeLine(object):

    def __init__(self, coro_func):
        self.coro_func = coro_func

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.coro_func()
```

An example of it in use:

```
>>> def summer(stdin):
...     sum = 0
...     for item in stdin:
...         sum += item
...         yield sum
>>> pipeline = PipeLine(lambda: iter([1, 2, 3, 4])) | PipeLine(summer)
>>> pipeline
<PipeLine: <lambda> | summer>
>>> for item in pipeline:
...     print(item)
1
3
6
10
```

So, I want to construct a PipeLine on the sequence of characters in a string.  Strings, in Python, are inherently iterable, so I figured it'd be no problem. But what I expected to work did not. This:

```
PipeLine(iter(src))
```

throws an error:

```
TypeError: 'str_iterator' object is not callable
```

Eventually, I tried:

```
PipeLine(src.__iter__)
```

and that worked.

My question: why did "PipeLine(iter(src))" not work? From what I understand of Python, it should.  What am I not understanding?

Running CPython 3.2, on Linux Mint 12.0.

Comment: I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'PipeLine' and 'PipeLine'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't you see the example functions putting a `lambda` around the `iter` call? The `PipeLine` needs to be passed a function that creates an iterator, not an iterator object directly. `iter(src)` is an iterator, not a function.

Answer (score 4):

From the code you showed, it's obvious that the `Pipeline` constructor does **not** take an iterable argument:  it requires a 0-argument function.  Indeed, look at the working example you gave:

```
pipeline = PipeLine(lambda: iter([1, 2, 3, 4]))
                    ^^^^^^
```

See the `lambda`?  The example did not pass `iter(some_list)` directly, it passed a no-argument function that returns the iterator.

So presumably

```
PipeLine(lambda: iter(src))
```

would have worked for you too.